# How can I use multiple iif in SSRS report?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssms, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have an IIF expression I am trying to use ...

=iif(sum(Fields!Actual.Value) > 0,"Increased",

iif(sum(Fields!Actual.Value) < 0,"Decreased",

iif(sum(Fields!Actual.Value) = 0,"No Change","None")))

or iif(isnothing(sum(Fields!Actual.Value)),"N/ap","None")

This is throwing me an error. Is there any other workaround for this?

Comment: What is the `or` doing in there? The above is mean to be returning a scalar value, not a boolean. Also, why tag SSRS 2012 **and* Reporting Services 2005 (the latter of which has been unsupported for 5~ years).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this it's much easier to use SWITCH. Switch uses pairs of expressions to evaluate and values to return. It's much easier to read and requires no nesting normally.

So for you example you can do something like this.

```
=SWITCH (
         SUM(Fields!Actual.Value) > 0, "Increased",
         SUM(Fields!Actual.Value) < 0, "Decreased",
         SUM(Fields!Actual.Value) = 0, "No Change",
         ISNOTHING(SUM(Fields!Actual.Value)) , "N/ap",
         True, "None"
        )
```

The True at the end basicaly acts like an ELSE, it captures anything that does not match previous expressions.

SWITCH stops when it finds the first match so depending on result, you may have to alter the order or each check but start with this and see where you get.

Comment: So the problem with that is the column Actual has 4 different values example: 100,-100, 0.00, and the null replaced with N/ap.
How do I Use that In the switch? using the above Switch condition it's showing me "No change" for values =0 and also the "n/ap" column is showing no change while the increase,decrease works.

Comment: As I said, depending on the values you may have to change the order, try moving the `ISNOTHING(SUM(Fields!Actual.Value)) , "N/ap",` above `SUM(Fields!Actual.Value) = 0, "No Change",`

Comment: That makes sense. Didn't work yet I will try all the options. Thank you so much now I understand how switch works.